# Beginner c++ How to return the number of digits in a number?

Tags: c++

The code below is what I've gotten so far. The goal of this portion of my assignment was to return the number of digits in a number, what am I doing wrong?

```
int numDigits(int num)
{
    int n, div, digits;

    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    digits=1;
    while(div> 0)
    {
            digits= digits + 1;
            div= 10;
            div= div * 10;
    }

return digits;
}
```

Comment: What 'is' wrong? Enabling warnings will be useful.

Comment: Set `div` to 10 once, before you first use it in the `while` test.

Comment: Hint: [`log10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10).

Comment: What is the point of this? div= 10; div= div * 10; Why not just set div = 100, instead of setting div = 10 and multiplying that by 10 to get 100? Does not make any sense.

Comment: Digits for 0 is 1 (an exception). For the rest: do it on paper, with clear names (though on paper you may abbreviate a `power` to `p`).

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning `div` to 10 inside the loop every time, instead of starting it at 10.  You also can just check if `div` is greater than the answer or not.  Also, you seem to be passing in `num` but then accepting `n` from stdin.  I've removed the stdin portion.

```
int numDigits(int num) //return the number of digits in num
{
    int div, digits;

    digits=1;
    div= 10;
    while(div > num)
    {
            digits= digits + 1;
            div= div * 10;
    }

    return digits;
}
```

A few other issues though:

1. Don't use `using namespace std`, it can cause problems in bigger projects
2. You don't need to use a separate accumulator, you can just keep dividing by 10.

Sample:

```
int numDigits(int num) //return the number of digits in num
{
    int digits = 1;
    while(num >= 10)
    {
            digits= digits + 1;
            num/=10;
    }

    return digits;
}
```

However, the more idiomatic C++ way would be something like

```
int numDigits(int num)
{
    //Note error handling needed for num==0
    return std::ceil(std::log10(std::abs(num)));
}
```

Comment: Source has `n` and `num` mixed together, removed the `n`.

Comment: would it be incorrect to use while(num/div > 0)? My professor gave us that line. Also is it necessary to prompt the user to enter a number for this function?

Comment: You could use `num/div >0`, but I find that more confusing, especially since it would be wrong in some other languages.  And in terms of prompting the user, your solution with stdin does not do what the comment says it should do (give the answer for num).  Having user input in a function of this type is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numDigits(int num) {
    int DigitCount = 0;
    while(num > 0) {
        DigitCount++;
        num /= 10;
     }
     return DigitCount;
}
```

Comment: The original post was asking what was wrong in her / his code. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define number of digits in num, not in keyboard input

```
int numDigits(int num) //return the number of digits in num
{
  int div, digits;
  div = 10;
  digits=1;
  while(num/div > 0)
  {
        digits= digits + 1;
        div= div * 10;
  }
  return digits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the solutions provided by various people with division operator and increment the counter for counting the number of integers until you reach dividend being '0'.

One more way is to write the input number to a ***stringstream*** and take the string length. I would say it as hack, but a simpler one though.

Answer (score -2):

```
int getDigit(int num, int index) // return the index'th digit 
{
    int result;
    for(int i=0; i < index; i++)
    {
        num = num / 10;
    }
    result = num % 10;
    return result;
}
```